# What are these called?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, recessed-lighting

I want to install wall lights in my living room.

I found these lights at my friend's workplace and I liked them.

I asked him where are these from, but he does not know.

I tried to google them but do not know what they are called.

So I wonder if anyone knows what are these called and how to install them

[image]

Comment: Maybe LED spot/accent lights.  They look like they would not light up an area/room, maybe just something like a picture.

Comment: those look like emergency lights that light up during power outages ... read what's printed on those lights ... they certainly do not look like `recessed-lighting`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic name would be

2-Head White Outdoor LED Wall-Mount Flood Light

Not exact your model found at Home Depot

[image: flood light]